# Pandas DataFrame How to query the closest datetime index?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How do i query for the closest index from a Pandas DataFrame? The index is DatetimeIndex

```
2016-11-13 20:00:10.617989120   7.0 132.0
2016-11-13 22:00:00.022737152   1.0 128.0
2016-11-13 22:00:28.417561344   1.0 132.0
```

I tried this:

```
df.index.get_loc(df.index[0], method='nearest')
```

but it give me `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Same error if I tried this:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("2016-11-13 22:01:25", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df.index.get_loc(dt, method='nearest')
```

But if I remove `method='nearest'` it works, but that is not I want, I want to find the closest index from my query datetime

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It seems you need first get position by [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) and then select by `[]`:

```
dt = pd.to_datetime("2016-11-13 22:01:25.450")
print (dt)
2016-11-13 22:01:25.450000

print (df.index.get_loc(dt, method='nearest'))
2

idx = df.index[df.index.get_loc(dt, method='nearest')]
print (idx)
2016-11-13 22:00:28.417561344
```

```
#if need select row to Series use iloc
s = df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(dt, method='nearest')]
print (s)
b      1.0
c    132.0
Name: 2016-11-13 22:00:28.417561344, dtype: float64
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. I believe your solution would work, but it just doesnt work on me...
this is my index type <class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>

Comment: Can you explain more? Does it return wrong value? Problem is with this sample of with real data?

Comment: dt =pd.to_datetime("2016-11-13 22:01:25.450");
df.index.get_loc(dt, method='nearest');
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: could that be when i set index, I set the time unit as 'us' ?

Comment: Do you think convert `ns` to `us` ?

Comment: i only have the df now, i dont have the code that created this df. But from my memory when it set the index, it is using 'us'...

Comment: Are you sure? Because `DatatimeIndex` is by default in `ns` - `print (df.index.values.astype(np.int64))`

Comment: Is possible remove duplicates in `index` ? `idx = df.index.drop_duplicates().get_loc(dt, method='nearest')`

Comment: Is there any way to query for multiple date times simultaneously? `get_loc` only accepts scalar values.

Comment: It seems the only way to do this for a non-index column is to create another df with set_index.

Comment: Seems as if this only works for series or dfs where the index is unique. Heres an example that reproduces the error:

`dts = [datetime(2020,1,1,1),
           datetime(2020,1,1,2),
           datetime(2020,1,1,2),
           datetime(2020,1,1,3)]
    idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(dts)
    idx.get_loc(pd.to_datetime("2020-01-01 02:00:00"), method="nearest")`

Comment: as mentioned by @HarryChil, `DatetimeIndex.get_loc` is now deprecated in favour of `DatetimeIndex.get_indexer`. This method requires a list and therefore is also the go to method if you want to query multiple date times as asked by @fhchl

Answer (score 33):

`DatetimeIndex.get_loc` is now deprecated in favour of `DatetimeIndex.get_indexer`...

```py
ts = pd.to_datetime('2022-05-26 13:19:48.154000')        # example time
iloc_idx = df.index.get_indexer([ts], method='nearest')  # returns absolute index into df e.g. array([5])
loc_idx = df.index[iloc_idx]                             # if you want named index

my_val = df.iloc[iloc_idx]
my_val = df.loc[loc_idx]                                 # as above so below...
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe jezrael solution works, but not on my dataframe (which i have no clue why). This is the solution that I came up with.

```
from bisect import bisect #operate as sorted container
timestamps = np.array(df.index)
upper_index = bisect(timestamps, np_dt64, hi=len(timestamps)-1) #find the upper index of the closest time stamp
df_index = df.index.get_loc(min(timestamps[upper_index], timestamps[upper_index-1],key=lambda x: abs(x - np_dt64))) #find the closest between upper and lower timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but while searching for the same problems as [Bryan Fok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403360/bryan-fok), I landed here. So for future searchers getting here, I post my solution.
My index had 4 non-unique items (possibly due to rounding errors when recording the data). The following worked and showed the correct data:

```
dt = pd.to_datetime("2016-11-13 22:01:25.450")

s = df.loc[df.index.unique()[df.index.unique().get_loc(dt, method='nearest')]]
```

However, in case your nearest index occures multiple times, this will return multiple rows. If you want to catch that, you could test for it with:

```
if len(s) != len(df.columns):
    # do what is appropriate for your case
    # e.g. selecting only the first occurence
    s.iloc[0]
```

Edit: fixed the catching after some test

Answer (score 1):

in case you are interested in an easy way getting nearest value from a DateTime-indexed DataFrame use [Index.asof](https://dfile:///Users/anaderi/Library/Application%20Support/Dash/DocSets/Pandas/Pandas.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.asof.html) method:

```
print(dt)
2016-11-13 22:00:25.450000

dt_indexed = df.index.asof(dt)
print(dt_indexed)
2016-11-13 22:00:28.417561344
```